# How do I handle ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost & reboot / restart in WiX installer?

Tags: installation, wix, burn, wix3.7

I am using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) to install per-requisites of our project, and I have used ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost to have a custom UI. I am checking for the Windows Installer version and installing it as a prerequisite, but it requires a restart.

How can I handle a restart in code?

I tried checking it in the following code but the `e.status` value in case of a restart is also 0.

#### Code

```
private void PlanComplete(object sender, PlanCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogInfoMessage("-------------->>  "+ e.Status.ToString());
    if (Hresult.Succeeded(e.Status))
    {
        this.root.PreApplyState = this.root.State;
        this.root.State = InstallationState.Applying;
        WixBA.Model.Engine.Apply(this.root.ViewWindowHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        this.root.State = InstallationState.Failed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engine will return if a restart is required in the `ApplyComplete()` callback to your [bootstrapper application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx). You can either decide at that moment to accept the restart and return `Result.Restart` from the `ApplyComplete()` callback.

Alternatively, you may want to prompt the user on a finish dialog or something to give them an option to accept the restart or not. In that case, you can return `Result.Restart` from the `Shutdown()` callback and the engine will do a restart after your bootstrapper application exits.

I tend to do use the second option most often in my bootstrapper applications.